# Compiler does not warn for type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Tags: dart

Compiler does not warn for this:

```
class Foo {
  void commit(bool data){
  }
}
void main() {
  final foo = Foo();
  final data = null;
  foo.commit(data); // runtime error: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'bool'
}
```

[image]
Is this intended in the design ? What is the motive behind it ?

Dart 3.1.4 version

Answer (score 1):

About [Dart's type inference](https://dart.dev/language/type-system#type-inference):

> The analyzer can infer types for fields, methods, local variables, and most generic type arguments. **When the analyzer doesn’t have enough information to infer a specific type, it uses the `dynamic` type.**

What does that mean? If you do

```dart
final data = 123;
```

then the compiler can infer that `data` is of type `int`.

However, if you do

```dart
final data = null;
```

the compiler can't infer what `data` is: is it a `int?`, a `bool?`?.

It then infers the type of `data` as being `dynamic` and thus disable the type checking on that variable, allowing you to call `foo.commit(data)` without any compile-time errors. Why the compiler doesn't infer `data` to be of type [`Null`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Null-class.html) instead of `dynamic`? Because the `Null` type is more explicit and indicates that a variable can *only* hold the value `null`. Dart's type inference tends to default to `dynamic` for flexibility unless a more specific type is evident from the assigned value.

To fix that, you can explicitly declare what type `data` is:

```dart
final bool? data = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

I get

```
The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool'.
```

on my lint report.  This is on Dart 3.2.  Where did you not see an error?

Comment: Dart 3.1.4 version

Comment: @TSR Randal almost certainly has `strict-casts` enabled in his `analysis_options.yaml` which disables implicit casts from `dynamic` to other types.  I would strongly suggest enabling that too.  See https://dart.dev/tools/analysis#enabling-additional-type-checks

Comment: Ahh yes, I forgot that my test "codepad" loads up "very good analysis", which turns that on.